# Change Datatable column to html form

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, datatable, axios

How to made date information into a button in datatable.

```
$(function () {
    $('#table').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            "url": "https://api-sandbox.londontheatredirect.com/rest/v2/Events/" + showId + "/Performances",
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'PerformanceId' },
            { data: 'PerformanceDate' }
        ]
    });
    /**/
});
```

Comment: in `PerformanceId` you want button?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
$('#table').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        "url": "https://api-sandbox.londontheatredirect.com/rest/v2/Events/" + showId + "/Performances",
    },
    columns: [
        { data: 'PerformanceId' },
        { data: 'PerformanceDate' },

        /*Here the code how you render your html button, a tag or anything else*/
        {
           "render": function (data, type, row, meta)
           { return '<a href="your_url" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Button name</a>'; }
         }
    ]
  });
/**/
});
```

[**For better understand Read this**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)